# Cannot Return an array created within a function Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an odd issue and I’m not sure what I am doing wrong.

I have the following function that I want called in viewDidLoad to load all documents in a collection from Firestore that will be displayed in a tableview.

```
func functionName() -> [String] {

    var NameArray = [String]()

    db.collection("Names").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                NameArray.append("\(document.documentID)")
            }
        }
    }
    print(NameArray)
    print(NameArray.count)

    return (NameArray)
}
```

The function throws a warning **result is being ignored**. I don’t want to silence it as I need the value, it should return an array with the document names.

When I tried the below code, it returns the array and count as expected.

```
@IBAction func fetchUsersButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    var NameArray = [String]()

    db.collection("Names").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                NameArray.append("\(document.documentID)")
            }
        }
        print(NameArray)
        print(NameArray.count)
    }
}
```

However, I need to be able to return the array created so it can be used outside the function. Is anyone able to help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of returning an array you need to place it in a completion handler.

```
func functionName(_ completion: @escaping ([String]) -> Void) {

    var NameArray = [String]()

    db.collection("Names").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                NameArray.append("\(document.documentID)")
            }
        }

        completion(NameArray)
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you aren't returning anything is because `db.collection().getDocuments` is an **asynchronous function**. What this means is that the function gets to "return" before the `db.collection().getDocuments` code is done executing.

"Return" assumes that the code will execute **synchronously** which means it will execute line by line in a predictable order. An **asynchronous** function is one in which we don't know when it will finish executing (which is always true of network code).

What if the network is down? What if it takes a long time to download? Since we can't know, we use a **completion handler** to "return" what we need once the function has completed. The other suggestions are great, below is another solution. As a note, it assumes that this function is part of class, and you want to assign the result to an outside variable.

```
class MyClass {

      var myNameArray = [String]()

      func functionName() {

          db.collection("Names").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
              if let err = err {
                  print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
              } else {
                  for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                      myNameArray.append("\(document.documentID)")
                  }
              }
          }
      }

}
```

Another small thing about naming conventions, variables should utilize camelCase, so `nameArray` is preferable to `NameArray`.